# How to calculate center of arc given the radius, chord length, start/end points, start/end angles (can be negative)

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, center, point

I am creating an algorithm to generate random slot tracks/circuits. I have all the coordinates to position the track parts correctly but I can't find the correct center points of the curves for drawing. From what I searched I know that an arc can have two possible center points. The orientation is calculated by subtracting the previous part direction angle from the current, if result > current then 1 else -1.
[List of coordinates image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zeo0g.png)
[Plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye0gT.png)